# How do I keep formatting on an Excel 2010 Pivot Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts

I have some VBA code that runs a SQL Query, dumps it into an Excel 2010 spreadsheet and refreshes the 2 Pivot Tables based off the data. I also have 2 Pivot Charts based off of the Pivot Tables, and every time the Tables get updated, the formatting on the Charts is lost.

I followed the instructions in [Section 12.3 of this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=VnCDbXKjSaYC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=excel+refresh+table+changes+colors+in+pivot+chart&source=bl&ots=otUiGYxPuw&sig=4eP9Awd7eeXwooEaGiUEuO7IC0c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBGoVChMI-KKDxeGcyAIVh1uSCh2cXAgo#v=onepage&q=excel%20refresh%20table%20changes%20colors%20in%20pivot%20chart&f=false) which suggested creating a custom chart type based on my formatting preferences and applying it to the charts that I want to have remain formatted that way. These instructions work great *if* I manually modify the data then manually refresh the Pivot Table - the Charts remain properly formatted. However, when I execute this code:

```
For Each pt In NewSheet.PivotTables
  pt.RefreshTable
Next
```

the formatting is immediately lost.

Here's what the data looks like before:

[image]

and my carefully crafted pie charts:

[image]

As soon as I update the data and refresh the tables:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Again, having the custom chart style applied will keep the formatting if done manually, but executing the VBA code somehow resets the custom chart type.

Comment: Short answer-don't use pivot charts.  Just use the pivot table data to input into standard charts (either by direct cell references or named ranges).

Comment: Oh, and the other thing is: Please don't use pie charts for that many data points, and please drop the 3D bezel effect. Why? Read [Save the Pies for Dessert](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf)

Comment: @teylyn - yeah, tell it to my boss. Realistically, we usually only have 4-6 elements, not the 15 I've set up my template for, but she want pie and she wants it shiny and curvy like all the rest... :/

Comment: @dav - I've seen suggestions on how to do that, however, I need an automated solution to create charts for 20 reports & the number of rows will change for each one. If you have a suggestion that will make nice charts without extra rows showing up as zero values (i.e. handle one chart source with different numbers of rows), **please** put it in an answer! I'll work that into my VBA solution, give you credit, and maybe even buy you a cup o' coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this without the use of Pivot Charts, all you need is a dynamic Named Range and a simple (if grossly formatted) chart.

1) Create a defined Name using this formula: `Series_A=OFFSET(Sheet!B1,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1)`, where
  - Sheet1!B1 refers to your first count cell in your pivot table (or any other reference, if your comfortable with OFFSET)
  - Count(A:A) is your column with row labels

2) Create your chart(s) with the series=Series_A (and any others you need).

As you update your pivot tables, the defined names will reference the expanding/contracting values in your row labels column and only return the values in your count column.  No 0's, #N/A's, or helper columns required.

Comment: Thanks dav! I got sidetracked for a while, but once I got back to this, that worked perfectly! I had issues getting Excel to accept the named range as the series source, then I discovered that (since the range was on another sheet) that `SheetName!NamedRange` would do the trick. I thought `NamedRange` would be sufficient, since it was defined with a `Workbook` scope, but Excel wouldn't take it.  Greatly appreciated. Since I couldn't get a couple of singles crammed into the USB port, here's your [cup o'Joe](http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Caffeine-Can-Boost-Memory.jpg)!